# I spilled water on my laptop and left it there for a day

Tags: laptop, water-damage

I spilled water, it was around 9cm in diameter, on my laptop. I didn't know what to do so I just unplugged the charger and left it there, without removing the battery and turning it upside down cause I wasn't sure of my taking-apart-laptop ability. I left it like that for a day until I took out the battery and turned it upside down, it's been like that for a couple of hours. What should I do?

Comment: Was it on when you spilled water on it? have you attempted to power it on since you spilled water on it (not telling you to, just asking if you have)?

Comment: I'd give it another few days and try to turn it on again. Leaving the battery in was a big mistake. Check for and clean up any corrosion this may have caused on the battery contacts. Still, it is hit or miss at this point. No definitive answer can be given; it'll either work or it won't. If it doesn't then it is likely that only certain parts of it are. It will probably be worth figuring out what is still good.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you're supposed to turn it off right away, at the very minimum, and ideally remove the battery right away as well. Its possible theres been some damage, but then again, 9cm is a measure of distance, not quantity... so it's hard for me to guess if its a splash or a flood.

In any case, take a look at the following informative video on the subject http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tASvbnODtq4